# Is it legal to wrap li in a?

Tags: html, structure, w3c

I struggle a bit to understand the documentation here: http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/terminology.html#transparent which is linked to from here: http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/a.html#a-changes

As far as I understand it the following code should be ok:

```
<!doctype html>
<head><title>Yo!</title>
<body>
    <ul>
        <a>
            <li>My list item is wrapped in an anchor.
        </a>
    </ul>
```

But when I paste this code in different validators, they all agree that the li element can not be wrapped in an a element like this. Am I reading the documentation wrong, or is all the validators I found outdated?

Comment: ["Permitted parent elements ul, ol, menu"](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html)

Comment: No. The only element that can be under a `<ul>` is an `<li>`

Comment: If you are asking about that code running on browsers, some browsers allow HTML which is not valid according to the w3c specs. See related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25559999/why-arent-browsers-strict-about-html

Comment: The question is purely to understand if this is ok per the specs definitions. Because when reading the specs I understand that it is allowed, but that might be just because English is not my native language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, you are not using a HTML specification. http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/ is just a "**non-normative** reference", and outdated (it’s a draft from 2012).

The HTML5 specification (which is currently the latest HTML W3C Recommendation) is https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/. [HTML 5.1](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/) is [currently a Candidate Recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/2016/CR-html51-20160621/) (it will likely be a W3C Recommendation soon).

*The following links point to the HTML5 W3C Recommendation.*

---

The content model of the [`a` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/text-level-semantics.html#the-a-element) is [transparent](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#transparent). The content model explains what other elements the `a` element may contain. In the case of *transparent*, it means that the parent element’s content model will be used. But the content model says nothing about where the `a` element may appear.¹

The "contexts in which this element can be used"² lists where the element may appear. In the case of `a`, it’s:

> Where [phrasing content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#phrasing-content-1) is expected.

So you can use `a` wherever you would also be allowed to use text, `abbr`, `span` etc. Note that the `li` element is not listed here (`li` is not phrasing content).

See the content model of the [`ul` element](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/grouping-content.html#the-ul-element): it only allows `li` and "script-supporting" elements (not `a`).

---

¹ Except for `a` elements nested in an `a` element, of course. But this is explicitly not allowed: "there must be no [interactive content](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-html5-20141028/dom.html#interactive-content-0) descendant".

² This listing is non-normative (only provided for convenience). You can see the normative contexts by checking each possible parent’s content model.

Answer (score -1):

*Legal Yes, noone will put you into jail for doing so.* - Valid? **No!**

**[W3.org: li – list item](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/li.html#li-context)**

> **Permitted parent elements**
>
> [ul](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ul.html#ul), [ol](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/ol.html#ol), [menu](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/menu.html#menu)

As stated in the comments some browsers will display invalid HTML, though validators will always warn you about your invalid code.

Comment: This is exactly why I at first also thought it was illegal. But then I noticed the the w3c spec I posted above, which I understand as the <a> to be transparent and valid to put in between elements that a set of children, as long as the child of the transparent element follows the permitted child elements. Even I struggle to read what I just wrote there. Not sure how to phrase this correctly.

Comment: You might understand the specs for `<a>` correctly but `<ul> <ol> <li>` are a different case, they have their own rules. It's like saying you're allowed to carry a gun in Texas, so you're allowed to carry one everywhere.